# Assign Parse Role iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have developed an app using Parse as my backend.

I'm able to create users (PFUser) ,login, and create custom objects just fine. I now would like to implement Roles and the role I have in mind will be called "admin".

The goal of creating this role is to know when a user is an admin so they have more access to things in the app. I read through the documentation but I did not understand it as much as I would have liked and I know roles are something you don't want to mess up.
So, these are my questions:

1. How can I create a user role called "admin" from the Parse Dashboard? When I click on the "Role" tab, it asks me to create a new row and then I'm not sure what to do from there.
2. How can I assign an already created user the role admin? Can I simply go into the dashboard and change the ACL there?
3. How can I check if the role assigned to the current user is "admin" from iOS (Objective-C)?

Thank you so much for your help!